# The three special Danish vowels æ, ø and å are not recognized in python list

Tags: python, python-2.7, unicode, ascii

I'm writing a program which is supposed to help kids and dyslexics with dividing a word into syllables.
For the software to do this it needs to count all the vowels in the word given.

I have made the code and it can divide any word correct if they don't include the special vowels.
However if I use a word with a danish vowel it's doesent count the special vowels and the word is therefore not split into the correct sylalbles.

This is my code:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
-*- coding: utf-8 -*-

import sys

wordGiven = str(sys.argv[1])

vowelsArray = ["a", "e", "i", "o", "u", "y", "æ", "ø", "å"]

vowelsFoundInWord = 0;

counter = 0
for char in wordGiven:
    if char in vowelsArray:
        vowelsFoundInWord += 1
    counter += 1

print vowelsFoundInWord
```

If I feed the script with the word "slået" it will only print 1. What can I do? 
I have already tried to write ord("å") in in list and in the loop, but then I get a an error: ord() "expected a character, but string of length 2 found".

What should I do to make it work?

Comment: And what codec was used to give the argument on the command line then? In other words, what does `print repr(wordGiven)` produce?

Comment: If I print repr(Wordgiven) I get the following: 'sl\xc3\xa5et'

Comment: Right, that is an UTF-8 encoded bytestring for the Unicode text `slået`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are using UTF-8 encoded data, but are assuming that all letters are encoded to just one byte. When you iterate over `wordGiven`, you are iterating over *bytes*, not characters.

Your assumption is incorrect; anything outside the ASCII character set requires 2 or more bytes to encode in UTF-8. For `å` that means you'll get two bytes:

```
>>> "å"
'\xc3\xa5'
```

Neither `\xc3` nor `\xa5` appear in your list of vowels.

Provided your input is also UTF-8 encoded, you need to *decode* that to Unicode, use Unicode vowels, and use that to test:

```
wordGiven = unicode(sys.argv[1], 'utf8')

vowelsArray = [u"a", u"e", u"i", u"o", u"u", u"y", u"æ", u"ø", u"å"]
```

You probably want to study up on the difference between *bytes* and *characters*, especially when it comes to codecs, Unicode, and Python. I recommend you read:

- [The Absolute Minimum Every Software Developer Absolutely, Positively Must Know About Unicode and Character Sets (No Excuses!)](http://joelonsoftware.com/articles/Unicode.html) by Joel Spolsky
- [Pragmatic Unicode](http://nedbatchelder.com/text/unipain.html) by Ned Batchelder
- The [Python Unicode HOWTO](http://docs.python.org/2/howto/unicode.html)

Comment: Can I make the python script return the result in single byte format so it can be understood by PHP?

Comment: @Zahrec: 'single byte format'? Not sure what you mean there. You can encode Unicode objects back to bytes with `unicodevalue.encode(codec)`; if you use Latin 1 (`.encode('latin1')` you get ISO 8859-1 bytes that can encode all of the Danish alphabet with one byte per character.

Comment: @Zahrec: that'd still require that the PHP side also expects Latin-1 data. You may as well have it handle UTF-8 instead.